# SELECT ONE Row with the MAX() value on a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a pretty simple dataset of monthly newsletters:

```
id  | Name          | PublishDate   | IsActive
1   |  Newsletter 1 | 10/15/2012    |     1
2   |  Newsletter 2 | 11/06/2012    |     1  
3   |  Newsletter 3 | 12/15/2012    |     0
4   |  Newsletter 4 | 1/19/2012     |     0
```

and etc.

The PublishDate is unique.

Result (based on above):

```
id  | Name          | PublishDate   | IsActive
2   |  Newsletter 2 | 11/06/2012    |     1
```

What I want is pretty simple. I just want the 1 newsletter that IsActive and PublishDate = MAX(PublishDate).

Comment: The other similar questions all appeared to be dealing with partitions of data and aggregating max value over those partitions. If someone finds this is TRULY a duplicate please mark it as such.

Comment: dude please explain your downvote.

Comment: So based on the sample, which one do you want to return?

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: @Bohemian tsql implies mssql

Comment: What happens if two or more newsletters are active and have the same (max) publish date? Do you want to see all active records with the max publish date in that case?

Comment: @TimLentine interesting question. In my case, PublishDate is unique (this is modeling monthly newsletters).

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
select top 1 * from newsletters where IsActive = 1 order by PublishDate desc
```

Comment: This did not work for me due to the "top 1" portion. I replaced "top 1 *" with "*", and appended "limit 1" to fix it.

Answer (score 15):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select id, name, publishdate, isactive
from
(
  select id, name, publishdate, isactive,
    row_number() over(order by publishdate desc) rn
  from table1
  where isactive = 1
) src
where rn = 1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ae677/2)

You can even use a subquery that selects the `max()` date:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
inner join
(
  select max(publishdate) pubdate
  from table1
  where isactive = 1
) t2
  on t1.publishdate = t2.pubdate
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ae677/4)

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TABLE Tmax(Id INT,NAME VARCHAR(15),PublishedDate DATETIME,IsActive BIT)
INSERT INTO Tmax(Id,Name,PublishedDate,IsActive)
VALUES(1,'Newsletter 1','10/15/2012',1),(2,'Newsletter 2','11/06/2012',1),(3,'Newsletter 3','12/15/2012',0),(4,'Newsletter 4','1/19/2012',0)

SELECT * FROM Tmax

SELECT t.Id
        ,t.NAME
        ,t.PublishedDate
        ,t.IsActive
FROM Tmax AS t
    WHERE PublishedDate=
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 MAX(PublishedDate)
        FROM Tmax
        WHERE IsActive=1
    )
```