# Selecting Max of Sum

Tags: sql

I am trying to find the maximum total in a query and can only bring up the total of all entries. So far I have coded.

```
SELECT id "ID number", name "Name", SUM(quantity*cost) "Total"
FROM distributioncenter NATURAL JOIN inventory 
GROUP BY id, name
```

Again, this pulls the totals for them all but I cannot figure out how to get the maximum total.

Comment: Provide an reproducible example. max of sum(quantity*cost) for each id? because i guess you have already rolled up on id level and you must be getting a single value,how do you wish to calculate maximum

Comment: The maximum of the SUM(quantity*cost). Looking to find the total value of inventory in a DC.

Answer (score 0):

i think you want MAX() that will return the highest value of all

Comment: Yes that is what I want but I cannot figure out how to get only the highest value.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13752023/select-one-row-with-the-max-value-on-a-column)

Answer (score 0):

Edited:

```
 select max(total) as maximum_value from
(SELECT id "ID number", name "Name", SUM(quantity*cost) "Total"
 FROM distributioncenter NATURAL JOIN inventory 
 GROUP BY id, name  
)
```

If nested query doesnot work and make different tables.

```
    create table want as  
    SELECT id "ID number", name "Name", SUM(quantity*cost) "Total"
         FROM distributioncenter NATURAL JOIN inventory 
         GROUP BY id, name ;  

select max(total) as maximum_value from want;
```

Comment: No, unfortunately that gives me an additional column of just the highest single cost. For the original code I posted, I get two results with 2 dollar values. I just need the query to return the highest dollar value of those two.

Comment: then you are looking for the second solution which I posted. Let me know if nested queries don't work in your dbms.

Comment: You can create separate tables in that case, I have uploaded the answer. Happy to help :)

Comment: Also if the answer helped you, kindly accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

Which SQL are you using? I think you're looking for a nested SELECT, which many SQL dialects support. In which case, the answer is:

```
SELECT MAX(Total) FROM (
    SELECT id "ID number", name "Name", SUM(quantity*cost) "Total"
    FROM distributioncenter NATURAL JOIN inventory 
    GROUP BY id, name
) AS XX
```