# Trying to select records (with max date) in where statement

Tags: sql-server

Trying to use`SUM()` and `WHERE` in the same statement and getting aggregate error

I have tried multiple ways to select only the most recent entries and then summarize them I want to be able to pull the 4 most recent entries in the DB

```
@total_value bigint,

Select @total_value = SUM(TotalMB) 
FROM TABLE
WHERE DATE >= getdate()-1
   and (
        RuleName like '%Used Memory%'
        or RuleName like '%Available Mbytes%'
       )
```

These are table entries

> 2019-10-23 22:00:00.000   3958    ServerA Used Memory MBytes
>
> 2019-10-23 22:00:00.000   16028   ServerA Available MBytes
>
> 2019-10-23 22:00:00.000   15919   ServerB Available MBytes
>
> 2019-10-23 22:00:00.000   49335   ServerB Used Memory MBytes

I am expecting to be able to take these 4 entries when i use the `WHERE DATE >= MAX(DATE)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SELECT ONE Row with the MAX() value on a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13752023/select-one-row-with-the-max-value-on-a-column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the next statement is a possible solution to your question:

```
DECLARE @total_value bigint

SELECT @total_value = SUM(TotalMB) 
FROM (
   SELECT 
      *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [DATE] DESC) AS Rn
   FROM TABLE
   WHERE 
      ([DATE] >= DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())) and 
      (RuleName like '%Used Memory%' or RuleName like '%Available Mbytes%')
) t
WHERE t.Rn <= 4
```

Notes:

- Order rows by `[DATE]` column in your table
- Use `DATEADD()` function to add a specified number value to a specified datepart of a date value.

Comment: Thank you again for your help Zhorov. I will learn and share this information as best i can to help others as well