# Get only First Row or Highest Value SQL

Tags: sql

I am trying to get the first row (also highest value of this query) it is now posting everything

When I try adding Limit/NumRow to just get the first row (also highest value) for example it causes an error in the query. The QUERY is

```
select
  title
, min(year)
, max(year)
, count(appointment) AS num_appointments 
from appointments 
group by title 
ORDER BY title 
ORDER BY count(title) desc;
```

Comment: try explaining more what you want, but anyway I think if I get you right, you can do so by using sub query in your select, maybe something like this: *WHERE MAX(col) = (SELECT MAX(col) FROM table)*

Comment: Can I see where I would place that subquery in regards to what I currently have? I have tried placing similar things before but have resulted in error

Comment: what is your dbms name?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SELECT ONE Row with the MAX() value on a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13752023/select-one-row-with-the-max-value-on-a-column)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below - limit will work for `MySql/Postgres`

```
select title, min(year), max(year), 
count(appointment) AS num_appointments 
from appointments group by title 
ORDER BY count(appointment) desc
limit 1
```

If your database is SQL Server - you can use TOP like below -

```
select TOP 1 title, min(year), max(year), 
    count(appointment) AS num_appointments 
    from appointments group by title 
    ORDER BY count(appointment) desc
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell OP which dbms this LIMIT is for.